# Go mod fails on Raspberry Pi + Docker Compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, go-modules

When I've two microservices written in Go, each of them with their respective Dockerfile which does this

```
# Build
FROM golang:alpine AS build

# Destination of copy
WORKDIR /build

# Download dependencies
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy source code
COPY . ./

# Build
RUN go build -o bin ./cmd/main.go

# Deploy
FROM alpine

RUN adduser -S -D -H -h /app appuser
USER appuser

COPY --from=build /build/bin /app/

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./bin"]
```

If I run `docker build` on them everything works fine so I made a `compose.yaml` file to run both microservices (and other stuff) which looks like this

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ../loquegasto-backend/migrations/core.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-core.sql
      - ../loquegasto-backend/migrations/core.categories.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-core.categories.sql
      - ../loquegasto-backend/migrations/core.transactions.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3-core.transactions.sql
      - ../loquegasto-backend/migrations/core.users.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/4-core.users.sql
      - ../loquegasto-backend/migrations/core.wallets.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/5-core.wallets.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
  lqg-backend:
    build: ../loquegasto-backend
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
      - PORT=8080
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
  lqg-telegram:
    build: ../loquegasto-telegram
    links:
      - "redis"
      - "lqg-backend"
    environment:
      - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
      - TELEGRAM_TOKEN=${TELEGRAM_TOKEN}
      - BACKEND_URL=http://lqg-backend:8080
      - EXPORTER_FILE_PATH=lqg-export
      - REDIS_HOST=redis:6379
      - PORT=8080
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - lqg-backend
```

This runs perfect on MacOS using `docker compose up --build -d` but running on a Raspberry Pi 4 it always breaks when running `go mod download`, throwing the following message:

```
> [loquegasto-infra-lqg-backend build 5/7] RUN go mod download:
#0 1.623 go: github.com/Masterminds/squirrel@v1.5.1: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/%21masterminds/squirrel/@v/v1.5.1.mod": dial tcp: lookup proxy.golang.org on [2800:810:100:1:200:115:192:28]:53: dial udp [2800:810:100:1:200:115:192:28]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod download]: exit code: 1
```

Sometimes it breaks with only one dependency, sometimes with all of them, sometimes with one ms and sometimes with the other.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect it to be using the ipv6 address for proxy.golang.org? Does it currently work correctly with other ipv6 addresses?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why it uses IPv6 instead of IPv4 on the RPi but I don't think that can be the problem here. I will investigate if there is a way to force to use IPv4 only.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some research found that my Raspberry had an empty DNS server so I set it to the Google's one (8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8) and worked perfectly.

Basically edited the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, the line `static domain_name_servers=` to `static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8`.

Thank you all!